# How to write the query of it?

Tags: if-statement, sql-order-by, case

Select all data from the games table and order the results by the cost of the production from the cheapest to the most expensive. If the cost of production is the same, order by ratings from best to worst.

column names (production_cost, rating)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT g.*
FROM games g
ORDER BY production_cost ASC, rating DESC
```